# For any closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ there is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ whose sequential limits is equal to the that subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Question: Let $A$ be a closed subset in $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that there exists a sequence $x_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ whose set of subsequential limits is exactly equal to $A$.

My approach:
I think this sort of makes sense me if we our space was $\mathbb{C}$, however, I'm not even sure if this statement is true or not. I was thinking if it's possible to prove it by starting to say that the set of all subsequential limits of a sequence in a metric space is closed. However, I'm not sure if for any closed subset in $\mathbb{R}$, we can construct such sequence.

Comment: Why would it make sense in $\Bbb C$? In the case of $\Bbb R$ itself, for example, $\Bbb Q$ is such an example. You're asked to show that every closed set is the closure of a countable set.

Comment: Can you tell me why this question is equivalent to showing that very closed set is the closure of a countable set?

Comment: If a set is countable, you can enumerate it as a sequence, then every point in the closure is the limit point of a subsequence.

Comment: @AsafKaraglia : $\:$ That doesn't work for isolated points, and ever after dealing with that, one still needs to use that $\mathbb{R}$ is not sequentially compact. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @Ricky: Uhh, if $x$ is an isolated point of a closed set $A$, then it has to be an element of *every* $D$ such that $\overline D=A$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : $\;\;\;$ Yes, but it doesn't have to be a sequential limit of enumerations of countable sets $D$ such that $\: \overline{D} = A \;$. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @Ricky: Enumerate each element infinitely often.

Comment: Note $\varnothing$ a closed set.  There is a sequence is $\mathbb R$ with no convergent subsequence. But of course that sequence cannot be chosen in $\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you know basic things about compactness. And give you two steps to begin with.

1. If $A$ is a closed and bounded set, then it is compact. Prove, even in general, that a compact metric space is *always* the closure of a countable set (or in other words, a compact metric space is always countable). You can do that by finding a particular sequence of open covers, refine each to a finite subcover and use that to define the countable set.
2. If $A$ is closed and unbounded, then it can be written as the countable union of closed and bounded sets. Namely, if $A$ is closed, then it is the union of countably many compact sets. What do you know about the countable unions of countable sets? Now apply the previous case.

Or, prove directly,

3. If $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ is covered by open sets, then there is a countable subcover. Use similar tricks to the previous two steps and find a countable dense subset. (This property of $\Bbb R$ is called *hereditarily Lindelöf*.)

Comment: When we prove "a compact metric space is always the closure of a countable set", so how can we imply "there exists a sequence  in ℝ whose set of subsequential limits is exactly equal to "?

Comment: In the case of $\Bbb R$ it's just a sequence that enumerates the rational numbers. In the general case, if $A$ is a closed set, take $A_n=[-n,n]\cap A$, then $A_n$ is compact, take the sequence we get from (1) to be $x_m^n$, and then define $x_n=x^i_j$ where $2^i(2j+1)=n$.

Answer (score 1):

First suppose $K\subseteq M$ is a compact subset of $\textit {any}$ metric space $M$.
For $n\in \mathbb N$, we have the open cover

$\mathcal A'_{n}=\left \{ B_{1/n}(x) \right \}_{x\in K}$

from which we can extract a finite subcover $\mathcal A_{n}=\left \{ B_{1/n}(x_{ni}) \right \}_{1\leq i\leq J_{n}}$ where $J_{n}\in \mathbb N$.

Then $\left \{ x_{ni} \right \}_{n\in \mathbb N,1\leq i\leq J_{n}}$ is the desired sequence, expressed as a matrix and enumerated in the usual way.

Let $x\in K$ and $n\in \mathbb N $. Since $\mathcal A_{n}$ is a cover of $K$, there is an $1\leq i\leq J_{n}$, a $x_{ni}\in \left \{ x_{ni} \right \}_{n\in \mathbb N,1\leq i\leq J_{n}}$ and a  $B_{1/n}(x_{ni})$ that contains $x$ so that $d(x_{ni},x)<1/n$ and this gives us a subsequence of $\left \{ x_{ni} \right \}_{n\in \mathbb N,1\leq i\leq J_{n}}$ which converges to $x$.

Notice that this argument will work even if $\mathcal A'_{n}$ has a properly countable (not finite) subcover.

Now, let $C$ be closed and unbounded in $\mathbb R$ and take $A_{n}=C\cap \overline B_{n}(0)$. Then the $A_{n}$ are compact and $\bigcup _{n\in \mathbb N}A_{n}=C$. Therefore, this case reduces to the previous one, because for each $A_{n}$ we can construct a sequence $\left \{ x_{k}^{n} \right \}_{k}$, which hs a convergent subsequence to every $x\in A_{n}$. Then $\left \{ x_{k}^{n} \right \}_{k,n}$ is a sequence for which for every $x\in C$ there is a subsequence converging to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal I_1$ be the set of unit length intervals with endpoints at the integers.

Let $\mathcal I_2$ be the set of half unit length intervals with endpoints at the half-integers.

Let $\mathcal I_3$ be the set of quarter unit length intervals with endpoints at the quarter-integers.

…

Let $\mathcal I_n$ be the set of $2^{-n}$ length intervals with endpoints at the numbers $k / 2^{-n}$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

…

Now start defining the terms of the sequence.

The first batch of $0$ to $2$ terms are chosen in order, one in each of the intervals of $\mathcal I_1$ contained in $[-1,+1]$ that intersect $A$.

The second batch of $0$ to $8$ terms are chosen in order, one in each of the intervals of $\mathcal{I}_2$ contained in $[-2,+2]$ that intersect $A$.

The third batch of $0$ to $48$ terms are chosen in order, one in each of the intervals of $\mathcal I_3$ contained in $[-3,+3]$  that intersect $A$.

…

The $n$th batch of $0$ to $n 2^{n+1}$ terms are chosen in order, one in each of the intervals of $\mathcal I_n$ contained in $[-n,+n]$ that intersect $A$.

…

Answer (score -1):

Hint: $A$ contains a countable dense subset.

Comment: Why does it contain a countable dense subset?

Comment: The collection of open balls with rational centers and rational radii is countable. Let $B_1, B_2, \dots $ be the balls in this collection that intersect $A.$ For each such $B_k$ we can choose $a_k\in B_k\cap A.$ It's not hard to see $\{a_k\}$ is dense in $A.$

Comment: Yes. I know. But that's practically the point of the proof.

Comment: Let me know if you have any other questions you already know the answer to.